# combination problem for marble with color and number

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

suppose I have 3 different color of bags, yellow, blue, red, each contain 2 marbles that are the same color as the bag.

I know the number of combination of picking 2 different color marble out of 3 bags is just 3 pick 2 = 3.
But what if the marbles are labeled with number, like this:

```
Yellow(1), Yellow(2)  - bag 1
Blue(1), Blue(2)      - bag 2
Red(1), Red(2)        - bag 3
```

How many combination are there for picking 2 different color with the label in mind? That means:
`Yellow(1) + Blue(1),
 Yellow(1) + Blue(2)
 Yellow(2) + Blue(1),
 Yellow(2) + Blue(2)...` There are 12 ways but I am not sure what is the formula I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you pick any one of the marble then you have $2$ ways to select the different marble

**Example: If you pick $\color{red}{\text{Red(1)}}$  then you can pick $\color{yellow}{\text{Yellow(2)}}$ or $\color{blue}{\text{Blue(2)}}$.**

And you can pick any of $6$ marbles. Means $6$ marbles each having $2$ choice therefore $$\text{Total number of ways}=6\times2\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=12 \text{ ways}$$

**EDIT: (If the marbles are not numbered)**

> As if only color remains different then if you select any color marble then you have $2$ ways to pick a different marble of different color again you have $6$ marbles then $$\text{Total number of ways}=6\times2\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=12 \text{ ways}$$

**(If the marbles are numbered)**

> If marbles are numbered and only different colored marbles are to be pick. Now, you have $4$ choices with each marble $$\text{Total number of ways}=6\times4\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=24\text{ ways}$$ As the cases such as $\{Yellow(1)+Blue(1)\},\{Blue(1)+Yellow(1)\}$ are counted so we need to divide by $2$ $$\text{Total number of ways}=\frac{24}{2}$$

Comment: @user1701840 Discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56810/we-are-friends

Comment: what if I have 1 RED, 2 YELLOW, 1 BLACK, 2 BLUE?

Then I should think like this: If I pick 1 RED, then I have 3 ways of select different marble.

And I can pick any of the 6 marbles, so I am looking at 6 * 3 = 18 ways, but it is not correct.

Comment: not sure if I understand that, I can pick Red1 and Black 1, that is the third way

Comment: But according to question you can't select the same number.

Comment: sorry I edited my question to clarify